# How to connect IP network to remote outbuilding

Tags: networking, ip, remote

At my lakehome I have a great Internet connection with both wired and wireless devices. And I also have a garage some distance from the house that I want to build an office into with a wired connection to my network and Internet, as well as add some smart Wifi devices (thermostat, garage door opener, etc.); but, my otherwise very strong Wifi AP in the hose is still not strong enough to go the distance to the garage. Essentially I can maintain a signal on my phone or Surface laptop about halfway down the driveway.

How can I get a reliable extension of my network out to the garage without running a long Ethernet cable in conduit underground?

Before anyone suggests a powerline connector, note that the power in the garage is behind a different meter than the house. I already tried it and it simply doesn't work.

I know of an aircraft hangar at the local airport that has a directional antenna that picks up a network signal from a building about 1/4 mile away. But I don't have a clue what to search for to find these devices, if they even exist anymore. Everything I try brings me to Wifi, powerline network extenders, boosters, etc. But that doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.

Ideally I'd like good clean reasonable bandwidth out there if I can. My house Internet connection is 1GB. I don't need all of that of course, but could use something quick-ish for TV streaming, etc.

Ideas?

Comment: What is the straight line distance between the buildings?

Comment: Stese, distance is ~1200' and I think I can get a straight-line view between buildings if trees in the summertime aren't an issue.

Comment: I've looked into the directional link devices as mentioned and believe this should do the trick.  I've ordered a couple TP-LINK CPE510's to try.  Setup seems straightforward (watched video) and this product looks to be just what I need.  I'll report back my results.  My only question right now is if trees, with leaves, will inhibit the signal strength over what looks to be a relatively short distance for these devices?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use two directional antennas with dedicated access points, or simply run a cable between the buildings.

Ethernet over copper (Cat-5e) is extremely low-cost but generally limited to 100 m and may be sensitive to sub-zero temperatures.

Using preterminated outdoor fiber isn't that expensive either. Probably the cheapest variant for this is 1000BASE-SX over multi-mode fiber (anything OM2 or better) with a reach of 550 m. You can use any switch with an SFP port or a separate media converter. The switch vendor's original SFP transceivers may be pricey but you can get "xxx compatible" transceivers all around.

Comment: just FYI, OP states he doesn't want to run a cable underground.. so i'd assume fibre would be out too. That said, it's going to be a fair more reliable solution than anything wireless.

Answer (score 0):

If a wired solution is out, you need a wireless solution.

For that you need a pair of transceivers/routers with a directional antenna, and a way to position them with free line of sight between them.

There are solutions you can buy for that. Keywords are "outdoor" and "directional", e.g. [TP-Link CPE 510](https://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-37_CPE510.html), but there are many more by different vendors. Look around.

You may need to connect the endpoint at your garage to another omni-directional router on a different channel to avoid influences between the long-range link and local clients around your garage.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution here is a Directional WiFi connection with Devices like Ubiquity AirMax devices.
https://www.ubnt.com/products/#airmax
Those are the ones I have the most experience with, and am very happy with because they are quickly set up and have a good throughput over a great distance.
Other solutions might be any Wireless Access Point with a custom build/seperatly sold external directional Antenna (years ago with Aluminium cans?)